# INSERT INTO <x> with *

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I'm trying to perform a series of table comparisons where each table represents a data extract as at a given date. As time has passed, the number of fields in the table has increased. Aside from a growing number of fields, the tables are identical in their structure, with all new fields being added as a far-right field.

In preparation for this, I'm trying to move the data from each table into local temp tables where I can index them and query them multiple times.

A summarised version is below. It would be called programmatically from elsewhere with populated date figures, multiple times:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##direct_RISK') IS NULL 
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 0 * INTO ##direct_risk FROM DATA_20191231 
    END
ELSE
    DELETE FROM ##direct_RISK


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##direct_lead') IS NULL 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT TOP 0 * INTO ##direct_lead FROM DATA_20200131
    END
ELSE
    DELETE FROM ##direct_lead

IF OBJECT_ID('DATA_20210801') IS NOT NULL INSERT INTO ##direct_lead SELECT * FROM DATA_20200131
INSERT INTO ##direct_risk SELECT * FROM DATA_20191231
```

In the full version, an index is also added to each of the tables and a filter applied to the SELECT queries.

Is there some way to maintain this simple structure without naming all of the fields which will not break at the INSERT stage when the number of fields differ?

Comment: what db are you using?

Comment: SQL Server sorry. Added it to the tags

Comment: "Is there some way to maintain this simple structure without naming all of the fields which will not break at the INSERT stage when the number of fields differ?" - in short: **no**. You should always name your columns in an `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

For the syntax:
`SELECT TOP 0 * INTO ##direct_risk FROM DATA_20191231`
to work for each of the source tables or views you will need to have the same columns.

I think that one of the simpler solutions would be to create a set of views, one for each table and in these views you will add columns created later, something like:

```
CREATE VIEW DATA_20191231_Normalized AS
SELECT
 S.col1,
 S.col2,
 CAST(null as int) AS new_col3
FROM DATA_20191231 AS S
```

All the views would then preset the same schema for your script.

Comment: I recommend adding `WITH SCHEMABINDING` too.